# Why is altering column types not possible in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cql3

[This link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#concept_ds_wbk_zdt_xj__cql_data_type_compatibility) details the compatible types for conversion
converting from int to blob should be possible but its not

```
CREATE TABLE test (id text PRIMARY KEY,created int);
ALTER TABLE test ALTER created TYPE blob;
```

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Altering of types is not allowed"

Is there something i'm missing here and 
is any type conversion possible in cassandra?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using? Check this JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12443

Comment: i am using **3.11.1**
... so is alter support dropped (to be supported in 4.x)?
there isnt a definte conclusion in the thread

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the cql compatibility list [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#cql_data_types_c__cql_data_type_compatibility), you will see that blob can be altered to become an int but not the contrary, ALTER seems to be quite restrictive.
I'm afraid that the best solution will be to create a new table...

Comment: ...or drop the column and add a new column with the preferred type also works too

Comment: @chris No you can't drop a column and add a new one with identical name but different type https://community.datastax.com/questions/8018/cannot-re-add-previously-dropped-column.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunatley you are restricted to what type of column you can alter to. You also cannot drop the column and re-add as an identical copy with a different type.

Two ways round this: Drop the table and re-create, or drop the column and re-create with a new name.

Corerct to Cassandra 3.11.5.